# Questions about Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I have recently started looking at the topoic of Fourier series. Consider the space of square integrable functions $L_{2}[0,2\pi]$. Where we define the inner product  as $(f,g):= \int_{0}^{2\pi}fg dx$ and the corresponding norm $\Vert f \Vert  = \sqrt{(f,f)}$. The fourier series of a function $f(x)$ in this space is defined as $$f(x) = a_{0} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}sin(nx)$$

Alternativley it says we can consider the set $$\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}cos(nx),\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}sin(nx),...\} ~~~~n=1,2,...$$ Which is orthonormal. Then for any function in $L_{2}$ the series converges in the $L_{2}$ norm.

**Questions**:

Why is the fourier expansion unique to square integrable functions $L_{2}[0,2\pi]$, why is this space chosen?

Can the orthonormal set defined above $\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}cos(nx),\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}sin(nx),...\} ~~~~n=1,2,...$ be considered a Schaduer basis for $L_{2}[0,2\pi]$?

Thanks for any assistance, I am just starting to learn about Fourier series so any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: $\mathcal F$ is actually only naturally defined on $L^1(\mathbb T) \cap L^2(\mathbb T)$ but can be continuously extended to a bounded operator on $L^2(\mathbb T)$ with norm $1$. The most apparent reason is that $L^2(\mathbb T)$ is the only space where $(L^p(\mathbb T))' = L^p(\mathbb T)$ (self-dual) yielding a lot of nice equalities. Note that $\mathcal F$ can be seen as an operator on $\mathcal S(\mathbb T)$ as well, but the Schwarz space is a lot more difficult to get into than the well-known $L^2$.

Comment: We are talking about Fourier series. They are naturally defined on $L^1$. Observe that $L^2[0,2\pi]\subset L^1[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Are stating that every $L^{1}[0,2\pi]$ has a Fourier series expansion?

Comment: Yes, but it may not converge.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre How would you show this? Do you know why $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ is of special importance?

Comment: Crleson proved in 1966 that the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function converges to $f$ almost everywhere. This was extended to $L^p$, $p>1$, by Richard Hunt. Kolmogorov gave an example of an $L^1$ function whose Fourier series diverges almost everywhere. $L^2$ is especial because it is a Hilbert space and the trigonometric system is a complete orthogonal system.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Would I be right in saying that a function $f$ has a almost everywhere convergent Fourier series expansion iff the function is in $L^{2}$? Also, does the extension result to $L^{p}$, $p> 1$ also imply that the Fourier series expansion converges in $L^{p}$ norm?

Comment: No. Functions in $L^p$, $p>1$ have a.e. convergent Fourier series. Convergence in $L^p$ holds for $1<p<\infty$. These are classical results in the theory o Fourier series.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre So Fourier series expansion of $L^{p}$ functions converges a.e. for $1 < p \leq \infty$ and in $L^{p}$ norm for $1 < p < \infty$ is what it seems you are saying? Is my 'if and only if' statement valid in the previous question?

Comment: That is exactly the situation. Your _if and only if_ in the previous question is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1700's these functions came up in looking at the vibrations of a string, and someone noticed that one could isolate the coefficients of an expansion
$$
          f \sim \frac{1}{2}a_{0}+a_{1}\cos x+b_{1}\sin x+ a_{2}\cos 2x + b_{2}\sin 2x +\cdots
$$
using an integral orthogonality condition: it was discovered that the integral of any function in $\{ 1,\cos  x,\sin x,\cos 2x,\sin 2x,\cdots\}$ against any different such function would result in $0$ for the answer. In that way one could isolate the coefficients by multiplying the above expansion by one of these functions and integrating to isolate one coefficient. For example,
$$
        \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(mx)\,dx = a_{m}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{2}(mx)\,dx = \pi a_{m}.
$$
Fourier conjectured that *any* function could be expanded in this way, whereas people before him believed that these constraints limited what functions could be expanded in this way.

Eventually, this was abstracted to an inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on functions that looked like dot product on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where one defines
$$
         (f,g) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)g(x)\,dx.
$$
This definition was immediately useful in isolating the Fourier coefficients. The only real qualification for a function to be considered was that
$$
         (f,f) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}f^{2}(x)\,dx < \infty.
$$
That led naturally to $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ defined as the space of square-integrable functions. For any two such function $f,g \in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$, this 'dot' product integral is absolutely convergent because
$$
           |fg| \le \frac{1}{2}f^{2}+\frac{1}{2}g^{2},
$$
a fact which follows from the simple inequality $(a-b)^{2} \ge 0$ or $a^{2}+b^{2} \ge 2ab$ for any positive $a$, $b$.

Parseval's equality (~1795) connects square integrable functions and square-summable sequences because of the mutual orthogonality of the functions:
$$
        \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f^{2}(x)\,dx = a_{0}^{2}+a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}+\cdots.
$$
There is a perfect correspondence between $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ and the infinite-dimensional generalization of Euclidean space where the vectors have coordinates $(a_{0},a_{1},b_{1},a_{2},b_{2},a_{3},b_{3},\cdots)$. The dot products correspond perfectly, too. If
$$
   f \sim (a_{0},a_{1},b_{1},a_{2},b_{2},\cdots) \\
   g \sim (a_{0}',a_{1}',b_{1}',a_{2}',b_{2}',\cdots),
$$
then
$$
       (f,g)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} fg\,dx = a_{0}a_{0}'+a_{1}a_{1}'+b_{1}b_{1}'+a_{2}a_{2}'+\cdots
$$
That correspondence was enough to validate the study of $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ as an important space in its own right, and as the correct place to study the Fourier series. It took until about 1885 to realize that
$$
             \|f\| = (f,f)^{1/2}
$$
was a way to define a norm for general function spaces, and could be useful for discussing convergence.

**Schauder Basis:** The functions you give form a complete orthonormal basis for $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$. If $\{e_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ denotes the elements of your set in order, then
$$
     \lim_{N\rightarrow 0}\left\|f - \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}(f,e_{n})e_{n}\right\|_{L^{2}[0,2\pi]}=0
$$
holds for every $f \in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$. Using the usual definition for a Schauder basis, this qualifies $\{ e_{n}\}$ as a Schauder basis. This orthonormal basis is where all of the infinite-dimensional discussions started, and it is the prototype for orthonormal bases. Schauder bases are generalizations of such Hilbert Space bases to other types of spaces, especially Banach spaces. The $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ convergence of orthogonal expansions is equivalent to Parseval's equality holding for all $f\in L^{2}$:
$$
         \|f\|^{2}_{L^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(f,e_{n})|^{2},\;\;\; f\in L^{2}[0,2\pi].
$$
Another equivalent is that the following holds for all $f,g\in L^{2}$:
$$
                 (f,g)_{L^{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(f,e_{n})(e_{n},g).
$$

Comment: Hi @T.A.E. Nice answer. Question, why is $(f,f) < \infty$ needed as a qualification? Does this imply that all functions that have has the condition that $(f,f) < \infty$ has a periodic expansion $f = \frac{1}{2}a_{0} + a_{1}cosx + b_{1}sinx...$ ? Could you motivate where this qualification comes from in terms of the expansion?

Comment: You have to be able to form $(f,g)$ for all $f,g$, which includes $f=g$. And, it turns out that assuming $(f,f)$, $(g,g)$ are both finite is enough to guarantee that $(f,g)$ is absolutely convergent, too. So, that's a nice fit.

Comment: So what you are saying is that for the definition of the inner product it important that $(f,g) < \infty$. What I'm asking is how does the fact that $(f,f) < \infty$ and $(f,g) < \infty$ connect with functions which have a periodic expansion as which you showed above?

Comment: @JohnDoe : Every $f\in L^{2}$ has a Fourier series expansion that converges in $L^{2}$. In fact, amazingly enough, the series converges pointwise a.e. for $f \in L^{2}$; this is one of the deepest theorems of the 20th century proved in the late 1960s. $L^{2}$ is equivalent to the sums of the squares of the Fourier coefficients converging, which means the discrete Fourier transform is a vector in infinite-dimensional Euclidean space. So there's geometry, too. All of it goes together, and slowly evolved as I mentioned, starting with discovery of integral orthogonality conditions.

Comment: @JohnDoe : You can see--after the fact of development, with 20-20 hindsight--that much of this has to do with energy, too. Sums of squares, whether through integrals or through discrete coordinates, often ends up being connected to energy: $\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$. $I^{2}R$. $\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}$. And then there's Euclidean geometry $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$. Understanding is incremental and often unexpected. And all of this abstract development paved the way for Quantum Mechanics, too. The Math was there even before it was needed because of the evolution going back to orthogonal Fourier series.

Comment: That sounds quite interesting. This is not in my area of study at all, hence the questions. Do you have any recommendations to good introductory literature for this? Is this your area of research?

Comment: @JohnDoe I really like Dieudonne's *History of Functional Analysis* for a History. If you like Engineering, you should at least try to look at Fourier's massive *Treatise on Heat Conduction* from the early 1800's; he was the real innovator (a public domain English translation can be found on Google books.) What are you after?

Comment: A good intro from pure maths perspective. What do you think of Alex's second question? It seems valid to me that the set is an orthonormal Schauder basis of $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @JohnDoe : These functions form a complete orthogonal basis of $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$. Schauder basis is a generalization of such bases to more general spaces. Everything in infinite dimensions started here. So, yes, this is the prototypical such basis for an infinite-dimensional space. $f=\sum_{n}(f,e_{n})e_{n}$ where the $e_{n}$ are the normalized trigonometric functions, and the convergence takes place in the $L^{2}$ norm for all $f\in L^{2}$. And $\|f\|^{2}=\sum_{n}|(f,e_{n})|^{2}$ for all such $f$, which is equivalent to completeness.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for all your assistance. What is the definition of 'complete' when used in 'complete orthogonal basis'? Also, as asked above, would the statement be correct that a function $f$ has a Fourier expansion if and only if $f \in L^{2}$?

Comment: @JohnDoe : Complete orthonormal can mean any of the following equivalent things: (a) nothing is orthogonal to all of the elements except 0 (b) the expansion $f=\sum_{n}(f,e_{n})e_{n}$ holds for all $f$ (c) Parseval's equality $\|f\|^{2}=\sum_{n}|(f,e_{n})|^{2}$ holds for all $f$ (c) $(f,g)=\sum_{n}(f,e_{n})(e_{n},g)$ holds for all $f,g$. These are all equivalent conditions on a Hilbert space for an orthonormal set; i.e. one holds iff they all hold.

Comment: Okay thanks. Is my statement correct that $f$ has a Fourier expansion if and only if $f \in L^{2}$?

Comment: @JohnDoe : Not exactly. It is true, however, that $f\in L^{2}$ iff the sequence of coefficients of the Fourier Series is in $\mathcal{l}^{2}$.

Comment: Since every $f \in L^{2}$ has a Fourier series which converges almost everywhere it must be the reverse implication you are saying does not hold. So are there functions with almost everywhere convergent Fourier series which are not in $L^{2}$? My statement was supposed to read '$f$ has a almost everywhere convergent Fourier expansion if and only if $f \in L^{2}$', which implication does not hold here?

Comment: Yes, there are other functions. $L^{2}$ implies $L^{1}$, but not the other way around. A simple function like $1/\sqrt{t}$ on $[0,2\pi]$ has a Fourier Series that converges pointwise on $(0,2\pi)$ to the original function. But $1/\sqrt{t}$ is not in $L^{2}$.  $f \in L^{2} \iff \hat{f} \in \mathcal{l}^{2}$.